# Apex trigger. Help me please, if somebody know how to do it please

Tags: apex, trigger

When creating and updating a Product object record, the trigger must check the length of the Description field; if the field is longer than 200 characters, it is necessary to truncate it to 197 characters and add a three-dot to the end of the line.

Code is here:

```
trigger ProductTrigger on Product__c (before insert, before update) {
    List<Product__c> prList = new list<Product__c>();

    for(Product__c pr: trigger.new){
        pr.AddedDate__c=system.today();

    }   
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = Account.AccountNumber.getDescribe();
        Integer lengthOfField = F.getLength();
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? can you post the code snippet?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read about [ask], then [edit] your question to include any code you've tried so far. This is a trivial task (7 lines of code), so a minimal amount of effort put in would be appreciated. We are not a code writing service, but we will be glad to help you fix any problems with your code.

Comment: I've downvoted this question, because you haven't shown a willingness to learn here. Like others have said before, we're not here to do all of your work for you. You need to put in some effort here too. I've pointed you to trailhead before. Once again, I think that working through a decent amount of the trails/modules at https://trailhead.salesforce.com will really benefit you and help get you up to speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a simpler solution to this problem.

Just do this:

```
if (String.isNotEmpty(pr.Description__c) {
    pr.Description__c = pr.Description__c.abbreviate(lengthOfField);
}
```

Complete Code (I added my snippet to what Pranay had already written for you):

```
trigger ProductTrigger on Product__c (before insert, before update) { 

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = Product__c.Description__c.getDescribe(); 
    Integer lengthOfField = F.getLength();
    List<Product__c> prList = new list<Product__c>(); 
    for(Product__c pr: trigger.new){
        pr.AddedDate__c=system.today();
        if (String.isNotEmpty(pr.Description__c)) {
           pr.Description__c = pr.Description__c.abbreviate(lengthOfField);
        }
    } 


}
```

Per the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm):

> Returns an abbreviated version of the String, of the specified length and with ellipses appended if the current String is longer than the specified length; otherwise, returns the original String without ellipses.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check if the `description` field is not null and its length is more than `lengthOfField`, then you have to substring the description till last 3 chars and append `...`

```
trigger ProductTrigger on Product__c (before insert, before update) { 

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = Product__c.Description__c.getDescribe(); 
    Integer lengthOfField = F.getLength();
    List<Product__c> prList = new list<Product__c>(); 
    for(Product__c pr: trigger.new){
        pr.AddedDate__c=system.today();
        if(pr.Description__c !=null && pr.Description__c.length()>lengthOfField){
            pr.Description__c = pr.Description__c .substring(0 , lengthOfField-3) + '...';
        }
    } 


}
```